# How to differentiate between two .snk file having same name?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, strongname

I have two project having .snk file with the same name? These files were added by previous developers. I am not sure whether the two files are same or not. How do I know if same .snk file is being used in these two projects?

Comment: A binary compare will tell you if they're the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two .snk files are the same, they should be byte-for-byte identical. FC is a program that is included with Windows that you can use it to compare two files.

`C:\>`**`fc /B`** ***`path\to\the\first\.snk`*** ***`path\to\the\second.snk`***

(The /B indicates a binary comparison instead of a text-based comparison.)

If the output is

```
FC: no differences encountered
```

the files are identical. If the output looks more like

```
00000038: 44 57
0000003A: 72 6E
```

then FC is reporting the differences at a byte level. The two files are not the same and you'll need to figure out what to do from then on, like pick one and use it exclusively.